# Fit the size of view exactly to the path I draw in it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

This is onDraw code in my custom view.
I draw the speech bubble with a path and I want the size of view exactly be the same as the speech bubble I draw

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        super.onDraw(canvas);


        Paint paint = new Paint();

        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);      
                paint.setPathEffect(new CornerPathEffect(15) );  
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

        paint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, getHeight(), Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));

        Path path = new Path();         

        paint.setShadowLayer(4, 2, 2, 0x80000000);

        path.moveTo(myPath[0].x, myPath[0].y);

        for (int i = 1; i < myPath.length; i++){

                path.lineTo(myPath[i].x, myPath[i].y);                  

        }

        path.close();
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);


    }
```

How can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
canvas.clipPath(path) 
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
//TODO
canvas.save();
```